# JavaScript division by zero in Chrome console output

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I was playing with division by zero in both chrome and firefox consoles.  Was surprised when I got two different outputs depending on how whether it surrounded the operation by parentheses or not.

```
> typeof 1/0
<- NaN
> typeof (1/0)
<- "number"
```

And of course NaN as we know is of type "number" though it is "NotANumber".

```
console.log(typeof 1/0);
//outputs NaN
console.log(typeof (1/0));
//outputs number
```

Can someone explain the discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `typeof` operator binds tightly, so

```
typeof 1/0
```

is interpreted as

```
(typeof 1) / 0
```

You get `NaN` from any attempted division operation between a number and a string.

Comment: that's strange because the doc below clearly states that typeof operator precedence is "right to left", in other words, right side should be evaluated first: https://goo.gl/V1aikc

Comment: The `typeof` operator is higher-precedence than the division operator. That's what counts. Left-to-right or right-to-left only matters when you're looking at a sequence of operations at the same precedence level.

Answer (score 0):

I think Chrome is evaluating typeof 1 and then the division with zero, thats why it's NaN. In the other case it's evaluating the whole division 1/0 that is equal to infinity.